# Spring boot application not able to load SPI implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an **SPI interface defined in a maven module A**. In **Module B**, which is a spring-boot application, I have defined `META-INF/services/<interface-named-file>`.

In **Module A**, I am having this code.

```java
public class NotificationResultPluginProvider {
    private static NotificationResultPluginProvider notificationResultPluginProvider;
    private NotificationResultPlugin notificationResultPlugin;

    private NotificationResultPluginProvider() {
        final ServiceLoader<NotificationResultPlugin> loader = ServiceLoader.load(NotificationResultPlugin.class);
        final Iterator<NotificationResultPlugin> it = loader.iterator();
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            notificationResultPlugin = it.next();
        }
    }

    public static synchronized NotificationResultPluginProvider getInstance() {
        if (null == notificationResultPluginProvider) {
            notificationResultPluginProvider = new NotificationResultPluginProvider();
        }
        return notificationResultPluginProvider;
    }

    public NotificationResultPlugin getNotificationResultPlugin() {
        return notificationResultPlugin;
    }
}
```

In Module B - spring boot app - I have an implementation of `NotificationResultPlugin` interface.

Now here is the pickle.

**When I run the boot app from intellij**, I see that (in below code) `it.hasNext()` is `true` and `notificationResultPlugin` is found. In this case my application is working as expected.

```java
if (it.hasNext()) {
            notificationResultPlugin = it.next();
        }
```

But when I run the boot app with CLI, using a command like below (note I am deflating the jar first and then launching)

```sh
jar -xf <jar file>;
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=12341 -cp 'BOOT-INF/lib/*:BOOT-INF/classes' <main/class/fqn>;
```

Then `it.hasNext()` is `false` and my implementation in Module B for given SPI is not found. As a result, my application is not working as expected. I am at wits end now.

**Other relevant information:**

My spring boot app, is not a web app. That is I am not exposing any rest end point. I am simply using `spring-kafka` with minimal dependencies.

What am I missing ? Any help is appreciated.

**Found solution**

As they say, mind works best when you are not trying.

ServiceLoader was not able to load the SPI implementation because `META-INF/services` directory was not in classpath while I am starting the application. Setting the class path correctly did the trick. Ergo, this is the change i needed to do.

`-cp 'BOOT-INF/lib/*:BOOT-INF/classes:.'`

Notice that **extra dot** at the end.

Comment: how to provide this classpath information in manifest.mf file

Comment: Why do you really need is rather more important question. As far as I can see, if you mean to create this using spring boot maven plugin only, then I don't see any straight forward way.