# Spring boot application not able to find SPI implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot aplication where I have defined SPI implementation.

When I run the app from intellij, it finds the SPI and my application is working as expected.

But when I  deploy it on linux server it fails to find the SPI implementation.

I saw somewhere that we need to give classpath correctly in order to read META-INF/services, due to which i tried providing from the `manifest.mf` file like below but didn't work.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: com.loylty.dataengine
Implementation-Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
Start-Class: com.loylty.rest.configuration.AppConfig
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.2.12.RELEASE
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Class-Path: META-INF/services/
```

[image]

My project structure is shown above

Edit :

[This questions has the answer but using CLI not through manifest.mf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68144546/spring-boot-application-not-able-to-load-spi-implementation)

Comment: check that `META-INF/services` is a directory. `org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceContributor` must be a `file` in META-INF/services` directory witch content `com.loylty...`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov this same works perfectly when i run on intellij but when i deploy it on server it does not work.

Comment: Is your goal to make it work or figure out why wrong configuration works (probably not) in IntellyJ?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I made it work using the command `jar -xf <jar file>;
java  -cp 'BOOT-INF/lib/*:BOOT-INF/classes' <main/class/fqn>;` but I don't want to do it by extracting the jar and specifying the classpath  like this . I want to make use of manifest file to do the same